# Detecting changes on Polyline area, position or shape

Tags: .net, autocad, polyline

I am trying to modify any Polyline XData ***if and only if*** its position, area, or shape (changes in vertices) is changed.

What are the possible ways to do this in AutoCAD?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using XData, some [DXF codes are transformed with their owner](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-AutoLISP/files/GUID-3481BF7B-73CB-4FD5-B421-C25BE92C6D56.htm). You can use the codes: `ExtendedDataWorldXCoordinate` (1011), `ExtendedDataWorldXDisp` (1012), `ExtendedDataWorldXDir` (1013), `ExtendedDataDist` (1041) and `ExtendedDataScale` (1042).

However, in your case, I will use the `Database.ObjectModified` or `DBObject.Modified` events. You can use [this approach](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/04/find-which-properties-changed-on-modified-event.html) to find which properties have been modified.

In order to get good performance, you should use an `ObjectOverrule` where you will override the `Open` method, save the state of your polyline if it is opened for Write and compare it to the state found in the `Close` method. Then you can change your XData in a `CommandEnded` event handler in order to be safe.

You can also use the `DBObject.OpenedForModify` and the `DBObject.ObjectClosed` events.

In fact, there is a lot of ways to do it, but the `ObjectOverrule` seems to be the best option, as you can set a filter on the XData. And when you override the `Close` method, you have direct access to the object and its state whereas in the `DBObject.ObjectClosed` event, you only have the Id.

Answer (score 1):

Kean has a series of posts on this.  He's handling the OnCommandEnded event to see if a series of circles have changes position/size.

Take a look here: http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2006/11/linking_circles.html